# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager- App Management Console -- Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: wso2

my Environments:

wso2mobileserver-1.0.0 |
Ubuntu: 12.04 LTS |
Java -version: 1.8.0 |

Deployment (server config. step 12) |
working in production environment (server config. step 13)

---

I am so excited about the wso2mobileserver and want to run it. Unfortunately I still stuck.

I read of course the doc and did all steps as in [General+Server+Configurations](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations)
manythings runs well. No Error by Mobile APP Publisher, Mobile App Store and Mobile Device Management (MySQL tables are there...). - can create new application... and published it, see it in store....

BUT I get Error:

1)
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} - The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To

maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.

2)
 in **App Management Console** (the system ask again about ssl-certificate that I accept)
After login (or when I am loged in), I get the following Error

> ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject} - 
>   Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
>   connection?
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:694)
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
>           at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
>           at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>           at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>           .....
>
> or
>
> DEBUG {JAGGERY.router:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException:
>   Wrapped
>
> org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
>   connection? (http#220) ....

Is that to do with the first Error message about keystore?

Comment: Did you try Android Server Configurations https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/Android+Server+Configurations and iOS server configuration https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/iOS+Server+Configurations

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing wso2carbon.jks password there are multiple places you need to change. To run the server first create the wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore.jks with the password of "wso2carbon" which is the default. Your issue is with the SSL certificate.